70’s movie about an accident at a research facility
I think this will be a difficult one as I saw it on TV as a child (In the UK, probably mid 70’s to the early 80's) and I don’t remember much of it, but what I do remember has stuck with me, and I’d love to know what the film is.
It could have been a made for TV movie, or a theatrical release that made it to TV.
It takes place in some sort of industrial type research facility in America, lots of shiny metal, and glass. People walking around in white biohazard type suits. Some sort of accident occurs and “everybody” is killed. There’s a scene with lots of people in white suits laying on the ground. In the control room (lots of red flashing lights), they detect that somebody is still alive because the can hear them breathing inside their suit. Somebody must go in and find out what’s going one. But because the facility is on “lockdown” they only way in is to crawl through a ventilation type tube, I remember one other scene where the rescuer is crawling through a tube attached to the ceiling, very high up, looks down and can see all the dead scientists.
Does this ring a bell with anyone? 

Perhaps andromeda strain?

It's not Andromeda strain (I love that movie), the style was more modern. All the people who died were inside the research facility.

There's a similar question over on Science Fiction & Fantasy where the self-answer was...
Warning Sign (1985)

The movie tells about the outbreak of a virulent bacteria in a secret military laboratory operating under the guise of a pesticide manufacturer. During routine work a sealed tube is broken, releasing the secret biological weapon. Where upon detecting the release of the agent, one of the plant's security officers activate "Protocol One," a procedure sealing all of the workers inside from the outside world and they are left to wait out the deadly effects. A local County Sheriff whose pregnant wife, the security officer, is trapped inside, and with the help of a past employee who is a known alcoholic, must fight through a government agency and the chemically affected workers to find his wife and put a stop to the spread of the lethal weapon. The former employee had started creating an antidote to the weapon, which the sheriff and his wife create and deploy.
Wikipedia





Thanks, but that’s not it. The film I remember, the scientists died, they weren’t “infected”, it was a more serious drama. Having watched that trailer I’m pretty sure now the film would have been made in the 70’s the styles are very different.

Hmmm, trouble is we're dealing with childhood memories here and you may be conflating multiple movies. The only other one I can recall of this nature would be The Satan Bug but there's no ventilation shaft in that one.
